# Get username on Server that uses digest authentication (Perl)

Tags: perl, cgi, digest-authentication

I have a webserver, and on this server I am offering some content that is restricted. Users must log in via digest authentication. This woks fine, since till now all users saw the same content. But now I want to write a cgi-script in Perl, that needs to know the user's name to be able to provide individual content for each user. How can this be be done? How can I get the digest-login-name using perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for `mod_cgi`:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_cgi.html

The user name is stored in the environment variable called `REMOTE_USER`.

Perl stores environment variables in the `%ENV` hash.